# I want formula for Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I often run into VALUE! errors in my calculations because they contain numbers and text.

For example:

- cell A1 contents look like this: 10b=30
- cell A2 contents look like this: 20b=40
- cell A3 contents look like this: 25b=45

If I want to add A1+A2+A3 into cell A4, I want this answer (55b=115) in cell A4?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the cells are in a1,b1,c1 then please use the below formula
=SUM (LEFT (A1,2),LEFT (B1,2),LEFT(C1,2))&"b="&SUM (RIGHT(A1,2),RIGHT (B1,2),RIGHT(C1,2))

Answer (score 0):

let column a1 formulas like;

```
10b=30
20b=40
30b=45
```

let colum b1 formulas like;

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("b";A1) -1 )
```

let column c1 formulas like ;

```
=RIGHT(A1;FIND("=";A1)-2  )
```

and let A4 like;

```
=CONCATENATE(B1+B2+B3;"B=";C1+C2+C3)
```

Note that this is not a dynamic formula. Only will work for 3 operands.

Here you go;

[image: here you go]